# Javascript var in property

Tags: javascript, properties, var

I have problem to add JS variable "vpath" in the code below:

```
var vpath = myarr[0];
jwplayer("player").setup({
   flashplayer: "player.swf",
    config:"config.xml",
    autostart: false,
    allowscriptaccess: "always",
    height: 500,
    width: 625,
    plugins: {
   'http//www.test.com/'+ vpath +'/proxy.swf': {link:"http://www.test.com/link.php"},
   'http//www.test.com/image.swf': {link:"http://www.test.com/image.jpg"}
    }
    });
```

There is SyntaxError: missing : after property id. Does anybody now how to do that?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use variables in property names inside [object literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Values,_variables,_and_literals#Object_literals) (the precise syntax and semantics are specified in [§11.1.5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.5)). The solution is to define the object first with any static properties, then add any dynamic properties to the object.

In your case, I'd recommend creating the the `plugins` object separately, like this:

```
var vpath = myarr[0];
var plugins = {};
plugins['http//www.test.com/image.swf'] = {link:"http://www.test.com/image.jpg"}
plugins['http//www.test.com/'+ vpath +'/proxy.swf'] = {link:"http://www.test.com/link.php"};
jwplayer("player").setup({
   flashplayer: "player.swf",
   config:"config.xml",
   autostart: false,
   allowscriptaccess: "always",
   height: 500,
   width: 625,
   plugins: plugins
});
```

Another alternative, which might be useful in certain scenarios, is to use an [IIFE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```
var vpath = myarr[0];
jwplayer("player").setup({
   flashplayer: "player.swf",
   config:"config.xml",
   autostart: false,
   allowscriptaccess: "always",
   height: 500,
   width: 625,
   plugins: (function() {
           var obj = {};
           obj['http//www.test.com/image.swf'] = {link:"http://www.test.com/image.jpg"}
           obj['http//www.test.com/'+ vpath +'/proxy.swf'] = {link:"http://www.test.com/link.php"};
       })()
});
```